# I need help creating/improving my for-loop

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, for-loop

I created a program to create a polynomial. However, I cannot make it to display the exponent in the correct manner.

For example, if I enter [1,2,3] in my array to create my polynomial I get back the polynomial: 1 + 2x + 3x^(2). What I want to get back is: 1x^(2) + 2x + 3. Notice that the numbers in my array are still in the same order. The only thing that changed was that the exponent and power changed to start from the left side (the highest degree begins from the left). I need help doing this part.

Here is my code for the loop that was sorting it:

\

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you try adding a second variable, e.g. `power`, counting *down* from `n` and representing the power of `x`? It's trivial.

Comment: But would the x begin from the left side?

Comment: Do you construct the polynomial from left to right? Yes. Then go ahead and try it.

Comment: You're doing yourself a disservice by getting the answer ready-made here. Rather, try to use the debugger to see where the program goes wrong at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Just initiate i to n-1 and substract in each iteration

```
public void printPoly1(int[] poly, int n)
{
    for (int i = n-1; i  >= 0; i--)
    {
        Console.Write(poly[i]);
        if (i != 0)
        {
            Console.Write("x^" + i + " + ");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
}
```

Comment: I ran this and it saids that index is out of boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Change this if part

```
if (i != 0)
{
    Console.Write("x^" + i);
}
```

To this

```
if ((n - 1 - i) != 0)
{
    Console.Write("x^" + (n - 1 - i));
}
```

Because the power should start from end of loop to start (like inverse loop). but you are iterating from start to end (normal loop). So subtract counter (`i`) from `n - 1`.

If you still didnt understand then look here. the first line is counter in loop and should start from 0 to 6.

```
0    1    2    3    4    5    6    // normal

6-0  6-1  6-2  6-3  6-4  6-5  6-6  // do subtract

6    5    4     3    2    1    0   // inverse
```

Comment: Your supplement material is helping me.